# Prop-function mock not being called

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component function like so:

```js
onSomethingDoSomething = async (arg) {
   /* logic */
   const result = await this.props.theFunctionIWantToTest()
   /* more logic */
}
```

With Jest/Enzyme I'm trying to assert that `this.props.theFunctionIWantToTest` has been called when `onSomethingDoSomething` has been called.

By a series of logging statements I can see that `theFunctionIWantToTest` is, in fact, being invoked during my test *and* by logging `console.log(theFunctionIWantToTest)` in my component I can see that the function itself is a mocked function. However,

```js
expect(instance.props.theFunctionIWantToTest).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

results in a failure:

```js
Expected mock function to have been called
```

My testing setup is as such:

```js
const props = {
  theFunctionIWantToTest: jest.fn()
}

const wrappedComp = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MemoryRouter>
        <MyComponent {...props} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    </Provider>)

const instance = wrappedComp.find(MyComponent).getNode()

instance.onSomethingDoSomething()

expect(instance.props.theFunctionIWantToTest).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Again, throwing `console.log`s in `onSomethingDoSomething` I can see that the function type of my tested function is a mock and I can see mocked results being logged *after* `theFunctionIWantToTest` is invoked, but the expectation fails. Why?

Comment: you probably need to use the `await` keyword in your call `instance.onSomethingDoSomething()` in your test, since it's an async function

Comment: Ugh. Such a simple problem. That seemed to work. Put that as the answer and I'll mark it accordingly. THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `await` keyword in your call to `instance.onSomethingDoSomething()` in your test, since it's an async function.